# Freeze the spinned columns in ag-grid

Tags: angularjs, freeze, ag-grid

i am using ag-grid to create flexible table, i need to freeze first 5 columns. With the spinned feature, it prevent those 5 to be moved, BUT user can still drag other columns into those 5 preserved first position. PLease help

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought: You could use the gridOptions.api.onColumnMoved event, and programmaticaly move the (not pinned) column after the pinned columns. Of course only if the user has dropped it between or in front of the pinned columns.